# How to set regex for website url pattern

Tags: python, regex

The url pattern is

```
http://www.hepsiburada.com/philips-40pfk5500-40-102-ekran-full-hd-200-hz-uydu-alicili-cift-cekirdek-smart-android-led-tv-p-EVPHI40PFK5500
```

This website has similar urls. The unique identifier is `-p-` for this url. 
The url pattern always has `-p-` before word which is at end of url.

I used the following regex

```
(.*)hepsiburada\.com\/([\w.-]+)([\-p\-\w+])\Z
```

it matched but it match many patterns on this website.

For example regex should match url above but it shouldnt match with

```
http://www.hepsiburada.com/bilgisayarlar-c-2147483646
```

Comment: What do you want to extract? Is it the word after "-p"? Or do you want to validate the URL?

Comment: Then move out the `-p-` from the character class. Use [`(.*)hepsiburada\.com/([\w.-]+)(-p-\w+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/jK9vE8/1) (no idea if you need capture groups or not, I guess you can get rid of them)

Comment: What about [**`-p-(.+)$`**](https://regex101.com/r/jQ6uJ9/1) ? This would give `EVPHI40PFK5500` in the first group in your example.

Comment: If you just want to check if a string contains `hepsiburada.com` and also `-p-`, you can just check it with `find` or `index`.

Comment: You can use `(.*)hepsiburada\.com\/(.+)-p-(.+)`

Comment: @VedangMehta I want to validate it. re.match(pattern,str)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a `re.match` you really need to match the string from the beginning. However, the main problem is that your `-p-` is inside a character class, and is thus treated as separate symbols that can be matched. Same is with the `\w+` - it is considered as `\w` and `+` separately.

So, use a *sequence*:

```
 (.*)hepsiburada\.com/([\w.-]+)(-p-\w+)$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jK9vE8/1)

Or

```
^https?://(?:www\.)?hepsiburada\.com/([\w.-]+)(-p-\w+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jK9vE8/2)

Note that most probably you even have no need in the capture groups, and `(...)` parentheses can be removed from the pattern.